# Проблема с возвратом значения из AJAX + Promise js

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

Есть функция которая делает запрос ajax:

```
let Ajax = function (url, data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                let deferred = $.Deferred();
                deferred.resolve(result);
                return deferred.promise();
            },
            complete: function () {},
            error: function (jqXHR) {

            }
        })
    };
```

Есть условие:

```
if(new Action().isUser()) {
    ...
} else {
    ....
}
```

Action:

```
function Action() {
      ....

        this.isUser = function () {
            return $.when(Ajax(getServer() + 'check', {}).then(function (result) {
                console.log('RESULT');
                return result.isUser;
            }));
        };
      .....
}
```

Но вот проблема в том что в условие приходит false и код идет дальше, а `then` срабатывает позже. 
Что я делаю не так подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: почему функция `Ajax` ничего не возвращает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас вы не возвращаете promise из функции Ajax, он возвращается из success обработчика, так же when здесь не нужен. $.ajax сам возвращает promise, по этому ваш код можно упростить до следующего:
https://jsfiddle.net/qpo8rxnv/1/

```
function Ajax(url, data)
{
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: { json: JSON.stringify(data) }
  });
};

Ajax('/echo/json/', { data: 5 })
    .done(result=> console.log(result))
    .fail(err=> console.error('ERROR'));
```

Если делать в том стиле, что делаете вы то код должен выглядеть так:

```
function Ajax(url, data)
{
    const deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: { json: JSON.stringify(data) },
        success: result => deferred.resolve(result)
    })
    return deferred;
};

Ajax('/echo/json/', { data: 5 }).then(r=> console.log(r));
```